# How to check two array in php

Tags: php, php-7

here i am having two array below the structure

```
$a = [
    "100" => ["name" => "1 A"],
    "200" => ["name" => "1 B"],
    "300" => ["name" => "1 C"],
    "400" => ["name" => "1 D"],
];

$b = [
    "user1" => ["100" , "200"],
    "user2" => ["100" , "300"],
    "user3" => ["100" , "200","400"],
];
```

Now lets take example `$b` user1 having the value of 100 & 200 , now want to check the value from `$a` 100 means what the name, 200 means what is the name ?

as per my array records 100 means value is "name" => "1 A" & 200 is "name" => "1 B"

> My expected answer

```
Array
(
    [user1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 A
            [1] => 1 B
        )

    [user2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 A
            [1] => 1 C
        )

    [user3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 A
            [1] => 1 B
            [2] => 1 D
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach`

```
$r = [];
foreach($activeGroups as $k => $v){
  foreach($v as $ik => $iv){
    $r[$k][] = $teacherActiveGroupNameData[$iv]['name'];
  } 
}
```

https://3v4l.org/vnUtc

Answer (score 0):

[**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [**array_map()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) might help you. `array_walk()` is to make an iteration over `$activeGroups` array and `array_map()` is for extracting name from `$teacherActiveGroupNameData` array.

```
array_walk($activeGroups, function (&$val) use ($teacherActiveGroupNameData) {
    $val = array_map(function ($val) use ($teacherActiveGroupNameData) {
        return $teacherActiveGroupNameData[$val]['name'];
    }, $val);
});

echo '<pre>', print_r($activeGroups);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/QCElT).